# How does this line php code work?

Tags: php, email

How does it work?

```
// Purge obsolete login attempts
    $this->db->or_where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) <', time() - $expire_period);
```

$this->db->or_where is codeigniter method,both 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' and time() return timestamp, I can't figure out why 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' will less than the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time` is a field in your database (most likely a datetime field) which is being converted to Unix timestamp format by your DB. So in theory it would be equivalent to writing this:

```
$this->db->or_where('time <', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', (time() - $expire_period)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no understanding of Codeigniter framework. But the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` part is an SQL function to fetch or parse a date as Unix timestamps. You may check it on MySQL [Date and Time Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) documentation.

So the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)` is actually fetching the `time` column on the table and parse it into Unix timestamps.

In conclusion, the above code will fetch all rows with the `time` column less than the current `time - $expired_period`.